# Print a file/directory name as it finds it

Tags: python

I am using `os.walk` to gather a list of directories and subdirectories in a folder.

Here is my code at the moment:

```
children = [x[0] for x in os.walk(dir)]
for f in children:
    print f + '\n'
print str(len(children)) + 'directories found'
```

I want it to print the directory or file name as it finds it, as a way to track progress.

At the moment it just prints each item in the list it builds, but what I want is for it to print as it adds a new item to the `children` list.

I could do something with threading to make a function printing the list as the list is written, but I don't think iterating over a list at the same time it is being written is a good idea, in any case, this was my idea:

```
from threading import thread
import os
import time

children = []

def fine_dirs():
    children = [x[0] for x in os.walk(dir)]
    print str(len(children)) + 'directories found'

def print_dirs():
    for f in children:
        print f + '\n'

if __name__ == "__main__":
     Thread(target = find_dirs).start()
     time.sleep(2.0)
     Thread(target = print_dirs).start()
```

I added the `time.sleep(2.0)` to allow the `find_dirs()` function to add an entry before the `print_dirs()` tries to print it.

Comment: That's... not what threading is for.

Comment: what exactly do you want to do here? you want to implement something like `ls -R` ? I don't see any input...?

Comment: If you want to see each item as it comes, why are you doing it in a list comp? Just use a regular `for` loop, e.g. `for child, _, _ in os.walk(dir): children.append(child) ...`

Comment: @jonrsharpe because I need to use the list of directories for something later in the script, this isn't the whole script, the rest of it isn't what I'm struggling with,

Comment: What I'm suggesting **still builds the list**. Your question is somewhat unclear.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I know it isn't, but it was just an idea. Is there are a big problem with using threading in this way apart from it being a rather menial task for a powerful tool?

Comment: The trouble is it's almost exactly the opposite of what threading does. Threading is useful when you need things to be done in parallel but don't care about ordering. Whereas for you ordering is absolutely the whole point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I assume you want to implement this:
want is for it to print as it adds a new item to the children list.

```
import os

def show_and_append(dir):
    lst = []
    # assume that dir exists.
    for i in os.walk(dir):
        print i[0]
        lst.append(i[0])
    return lst

children = show_and_append('/tmp/')
```

Comment: Per my comment above you can use sensible naming to make the loop much easier to read, and make it clear that you're only using one of the three things `os.walk` returns.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I appreciate that. what happens if you refer to `_`? i assume you will get the first _ from the for loop statement?

Comment: No, you will get the last one.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to see whats been added you could wrap the find result in a function like this,

```
def res(x)
    print x
    return x

children = [res(fold) for (fold, dirs, files) in os.walk(dir)]
```

You can then combine this with a condition, i.e. for keeping only folders with `tmp` in its name

```
children = [res(fold) for (fold, dirs, files) in os.walk(dir) if 'tmp' in fold]
```

however I doubt the usefulness.